# Riemannian symmetric space of dimension $n$ and rank $n-1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I need to cover a case of $n$-dimensional locally symmetric Riemannian space of rank $n-1$. Is there a simple proof that there is no such irreducible space ($n>4$)? If I need to cite the Cartan classification for that, which concrete paper/book you suggest?

Comment: Multiply hyperbolic plane (or 2d sphere) by the Euclidean space of suitable dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, but what about irreducible ones?

Comment: Just go through the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space and references therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An irreducible symmetric space $M$ of dimension $n$ and rank $n-1$ has dimension $n=2$.
Indeed, the rank is the codimension of a principal orbit of the isotropy group $K$ at $p \in M$ acting on the tangent space $T_pM$. So the $K$-orbits are one dimensional. Now any monoparametric subgroup of $K$ has a one dimensional orbit contained in a $2$-dimensional subspace of $T_pM$ hence $K$ has a one dimensional orbit contained in a $2$-dimensional subspace of $T_pM$. So $K$ has an invariant $2$-dimensional subspace in $T_pM$. But $K$ is the holonomy group of $M$ at $p$ hence $K$ acts irreducibly on $T_pM$.  Then $dim(T_p M)=2$.